# SHA-256 in Office Scripts is returning an empty object

Tags: office-scripts

I found some code online to create use SHA-256 in JavaScript. But I'm not able to get it working in Office Scripts.

This is my code below:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let temp = sha256("abc123")
  console.log(temp)
}

async function sha256(message:string) {
  // encode as UTF-8
  const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(message);

  // hash the message
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);

  // convert ArrayBuffer to Array
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));


  // convert bytes to hex string                  
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')
  return hashHex;
}
```

When I look at the console I see `{}`. From what I can tell, it should be working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it looks like the fix is relatively simple. The `sha256()` function is an async function. And I'm trying to call it from the main function which by default is not async. So in order to call it, I need to add the `async` keyword before the main function. And when I call `sha256()` I need to use the `await` keyword.

```js
    async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let temp = await sha256("abc123")
      console.log(temp)
    }
    
    async function sha256(message:string) {
      // encode as UTF-8
      const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
    
      // hash the message
      const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);
    
      // convert ArrayBuffer to Array
      const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
    
    
      // convert bytes to hex string                  
      const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')
      return hashHex;
    }
```

With this update I know show the following output in the console: "6ca13d52ca70c883e0f0bb101e425a89e8624de51db2d2392593af6a84118090"